# Combine Arrays in R if Column name Match

Tags: r, list, vector, merge

I'm starting in R and I'm struggling with this... I would appreciate if someone of you could advice me about how to do this... Basically I have two lists...

```
List1
2013 2014 2015   
3     16     6

List2
2010  2011  2012  2013  2014  2015  2016  2017 
201.5 268.5 106.0 205.0 392.0 348.0 307.0  64.0
```

Having these two list I would like to get something like this....

```
List3
2013  2014  2015  2016  2017 
205.0 392.0 348.0 0     0
```

Or this could also be OK

```
List 3
2013  2014  2015  
205.0 392.0 348.0
```

I have tried creating a vector but i cannot pass the year Colname to it, any idea how could I get the result I want?

Thanks in advance, this is the code I used...

```
PREvsCOR=function(){ 
  start<- which(names(List2) == min(names(List1)))
  fin <- which(names(List2) == max(names(List1)))
  a <- vector(mode="numeric", length = (fin-start)+1)
  for ( i in 1:length(a)){
    a[i] <-  List1[i] / List2[start]
    start<- start+ 1
  }
  return(a)
  }   # fin de PREvsCOR
```

Output of the function:

```
[1] 0.01463415 0.04081633 0.01724138
```

If I try to give name to columns by using:

```
colnames(precor) <- names(list1)
```

I get this error:

> Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("2013", "2014", "2015")) : 
>     attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions

Comment: DO you have a `list` or `vector` or `matrix`?

Comment: I get list1 and list2 by using **Tapply** which I think returns a list object

Comment: For your `List3`, do you intend to omit the years *before* those listed? I suspect it might be better to store these in a data.frame with two columns: `year` and `value`. From there you could easily use joins (base-R: [`merge`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html), or [`dplyr::left_join` and family](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/two-table.html)) to manage your sets.

Comment: I checked both, they are arrays

Comment: Maybe you need `List2[match(names(List1), names(List2))]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for you fast response! Appreciate it!

Ronak Shah got me to the answer. Other ideas might be good too, but this one was the simpliest and the one that achieved that I wanted the best way.

I simply did what he said to create another array:

```
List2[match(names(List1), names(List2))]
```

Then did the calculation I needed to do:

```
list3 <- list1 / List2[match(names(List1), names(List2))]
```